# What web platform has files that end in .sdo?

Tags: asp.net, oracle, web-services, web

I am looking at a URL that ends in .sdo, as in

```
http://somesite/somefolder/doc.sdo
```

I know that if you have an asp.net site the files will end in

```
http://somesite/somefolder/doc.aspx
```

I also know that oracle has something called "sdo" -- but I don't totally understand what it does.

```
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15523_01/integration.1111/e10224/sca_sdo_ejb.htm#CCGHEBJF
```

What kind of platform supports sdo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this link - http://filext.com/file-extension/SDO

The SDO file type is primarily associated with 'DB/TextWorks' by Inmagic, Inc.. Inmagic TextWorks and WebPublisher PRO together provide a do-it-yourself customizable solution for information management.

Answer (score 0):

.sdo is for DB/TextWorks (Database Deferred Update Directory)